# Uploading files to a web service into multiple folders using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Just wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

I am uploading multiple files to different folders in a web service.

Currently, I have got all the paths for the files being uploaded written in a CSV with their location to where they need to be uploaded to. (This currently works)

The files being uploaded do have a similar name to the location to which it will be sent to e.g. File A to Folder A, File B to Folder B.

Is there a better way in which I can achieve the same thing but in a more file name to match similar folder name without giving the location in a CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your filename has a pattern to decide to which server it should upload to,use beanshell preprocessor to finalise the folder name.

For example - File A to be uploaded to Folder A,your preprocessor sample code can be like

```
    String file=vars.get("fileName");//filename variable holds file names
    if(file.charAt(file.length()-1)=='A')//checks the whether last char is A
    {
    vars.put("foldertobeUploaded","Folder A");
    }
    else
    {
    vars.put("foldertobeUploaded","Folder B");
    }
```

and use ${foldertobeUploaded} wherever you want to use in sampler.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter comes with [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) where you can define a condition. If condition is true, If Controller's child(ren) sample(rs) will be executed.

Something like:

- If Controller: condition `"${someJMeterVariable}".endsWith("A")`

  - HTTP Request to put file into `Folder A`
- If Controller: condition `"${someJMeterVariable}".endsWith("B")`

  - HTTP Request to put file into `Folder B`
- etc.

References:

- [JavaScript String endsWith() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_endswith.asp)
- [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)